# How to stop morning Riots?

Tags: prison-architect

Every morning in my [prison](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=696081249), when all of the Prisoners wake up for Shower time, as soon as they get to the Showers they all start fighting (in every Shower). I'm not sure exactly why, because the only need that is high is Hygiene, which they should be dealing with in the Shower. I have one Gang with 80+ members, and so almost every fight includes one. This breaks out more fighting, and chaos ensues.

For a while I had `EnableMisconduct` turned off, but decided to see what would happen when I turned it back on. The prison is [shared to the Workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=696081249) now, so I can't change the save file.

**How can I stop these morning Riots?**

Comment: [tag:murder] all the prisoners. then they will stop rioting.

Comment: @Dragonrage and people called me a harsh warden.. damn :)

Comment: @TimS. hey, you can't tell me it's not an effective approach

Comment: @Dragonrage never said that... it does stop the rioting :)

Comment: I have found that several small shower causes less morning riot (there are less people in the same room). And even if they riot it will stay small.

Answer (score 4):

If it's truly hygiene that is causing them to riot (ie that is their only need), perhaps have the last couple hours of your sleep regime changed to "free time", so they can sleep if they want to sleep, or they can get an early start on getting their criminal bodies clean and shiny as not to interfere with all of the gang-related activities.

I had a major problem with shower riots in the morning as well, but aside from putting a shower in every cell (I'm not Warden Claus over here) I found that letting them out of their cells a bit earlier than necessary resolved much of that issue.